# how to update multiple check box value when retrived from database

Tags: jsp, taglib

using this tag lib

```
    <%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

but getting error

**The function contains must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified**

i am using this method . to make multiple check boxed checked while fetching from database

```
   <c:set var="medium" value="<%=rs.getString("medium")%>" />

       English
    <input type="checkbox" name="C1" <c:if test="${fn:medium.contains('English')}">checked</c:if>>
    Kannada
    <input type="checkbox" name="C1"
           <c:if test="${medium.contains('Kannada')}">checked</c:if>>
    Hindi
    <input type="checkbox" name="C1"
           <c:if test="${medium.contains('Hindi')}">checked</c:if>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to :

```
    English
    <input type="checkbox" name="C1" 
           <c:if test="${fn:contains(medium,'English')}">checked</c:if>>
    Kannada
    <input type="checkbox" name="C1"
           <c:if test="${fn:contains(medium,'Kannada')}">checked</c:if>>
    Hindi
    <input type="checkbox" name="C1"
           <c:if test="${fn:contains(medium,'Hindi')}">checked</c:if>>
```

and include taglibs

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_function_contains.htm

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this `taglib` for `fm` support:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
```

And try to change

```
<c:if test="${fn:medium.contains('English')}">checked</c:if>
```

into

```
<c:if test="${fn:contains(medium, 'English')}">checked</c:if>
```

Comment: thank you very much . u saved my time :) . super coding . i got accurate result

Answer (score 0):

use this simple and single line solution.
no need to add any library and function.

```
<form:checkbox class="form-check-input" path="isMultiple" id="isMultiple" value="Yes" ${(isMultiple=='Yes')?'checked':''}></form:checkbox>
```